# How to customize the node info being shared on Facebook and other sites?

Tags: 7, social-network

[This article](http://drupalst.com/blog/how-your-drupal-7-application-appear-facebook) describes how to use hook_process_html() to customize the node info when you embed your page into Facebook or other sites.

Is this still the best way to go or are there other ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the [Meta Tags](http://drupal.org/project/metatag/) module. It makes the Facebook Open Graph information easy to update and configurable per node, if necessary.